# update textview from seekbar very slow

Tags: android, performance, textview

I want to update a textview from the seekbar onProgressChanged.

For better performance I have set the textview to fill_parent. These works at two devices very well.

On a third device each update cause a feelable delay.

For testing purpose I changed the System that it update the textview every second... but also there there is a short delay while moving the seekbar (but only every second)... so the textview.settext cause the delay...

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
    if (b) {
        if(oldProcess != i) {
            String sendValue = String.format("%03d", i);
            txtHitchPositionOverlay.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            mainApp.writeHitchSet(sendValue);
            oldProcess = i;
        }
    }
}
```

For testing purpose I comment line 5 and 7 out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading the Tablet I wasn't able to reproduce this problem...